# Redesign the representation of the process

Tags: python, svg, graph, pydot

I have a problem. I want to draw a proces unfortunately it does not look good as I want. Is there an option to make the arrows more angular, create a box with and add messages to edges or nodes.

Is there an option to redesign the process with `PyDot` that it looks more like the image below?

[image]

```py
import pydot
from IPython.display import SVG

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph', rankdir='LR')

#start_node = pydot.Node("Start", shape="circle")
#end_node = pydot.Node("End", shape="doublecircle")
task_node1 = pydot.Node("Task1", shape="box", )
task_node2 = pydot.Node("Task2", shape="box")
task_node3 = pydot.Node("Task3", shape="box")
task_node4 = pydot.Node("Task4", shape="box")
task_node5 = pydot.Node("Task5", shape="box")
task_node6 = pydot.Node("Task6", shape="box")
task_node7 = pydot.Node("Task7", shape="box")
task_node8 = pydot.Node("Task8", shape="box")
task_node9 = pydot.Node("Task9", shape="box")
task_node10 = pydot.Node("Task10", shape="box")
task_node11 = pydot.Node("Task11", shape="box")

#graph.add_node(start_node)
#graph.add_node(end_node)
graph.add_node(task_node1)
graph.add_node(task_node2)
graph.add_node(task_node3)
graph.add_node(task_node4)
graph.add_node(task_node5)
graph.add_node(task_node6)
graph.add_node(task_node7)
graph.add_node(task_node8)
graph.add_node(task_node9)
graph.add_node(task_node10)
graph.add_node(task_node11)

task1_to_task2_edge = pydot.Edge("Task1", "Task2")
task2_to_task3_edge = pydot.Edge("Task2", "Task3")
task2_to_task4_edge = pydot.Edge("Task2", "Task4")
task3_to_task4_edge = pydot.Edge("Task3", "Task4")
task3_to_task5_edge = pydot.Edge("Task3", "Task5")
task4_to_task5_edge = pydot.Edge("Task4", "Task5")
task5_to_task6_edge = pydot.Edge("Task5", "Task6")
task6_to_task7_edge = pydot.Edge("Task6", "Task7")
task7_to_task8_edge = pydot.Edge("Task7", "Task8")
task8_to_task7_edge = pydot.Edge("Task8", "Task7")
task8_to_task9_edge = pydot.Edge("Task8", "Task9")
task9_to_task10_edge = pydot.Edge("Task9", "Task10")
task10_to_task1_edge = pydot.Edge("Task10", "Task1")
task3_to_task11_edge = pydot.Edge("Task3", "Task11")
task11_to_task1_edge = pydot.Edge("Task11", "Task1")

graph.add_edge(task1_to_task2_edge)
graph.add_edge(task2_to_task3_edge)
graph.add_edge(task2_to_task4_edge)
graph.add_edge(task3_to_task4_edge)
graph.add_edge(task3_to_task5_edge)
graph.add_edge(task4_to_task5_edge)
graph.add_edge(task5_to_task6_edge)
graph.add_edge(task6_to_task7_edge)
graph.add_edge(task7_to_task8_edge)
graph.add_edge(task8_to_task7_edge)
graph.add_edge(task8_to_task9_edge)
graph.add_edge(task9_to_task10_edge)
graph.add_edge(task10_to_task1_edge)
graph.add_edge(task3_to_task11_edge)
graph.add_edge(task11_to_task1_edge)



graph.write_svg("diagram.svg")
SVG('diagram.svg')
```

[image]